# How to format heading in excel / csv using C#

Tags: c#, .net, csv, export-to-excel

My code will generate the excel document like this

```
|id  | Name  | Address  | company_Name | Destination|
|----|-------|----------|--------------|------------|
|##1 | xxx   | xxxx     | xxx          | xxxxx      |
```

But I want like this...

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| Personal Information  |   Working INFO            |
-----------------------------------------------------
|id  | Name  | Address  | company_Name | Destination|
|----|-------|----------|--------------|------------|
|##1 | xxx   | xxxx     | xxx          | xxxxx      |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I get the data from the API and I will save it using the `SaveFileDialog`

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
dialog.Title = "Save file as...";
dialog.Filter = "Text files (*.csv)|*.csv";
dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(dialog.FileName); //open the file for writing.
     writer.Write(report); //write the current date to the file. change this with your date or something.
     writer.Close(); //remember to close the file again.
     writer.Dispose(); //remember to dispose it from the memory.

     program.ShowInformationMessage("File Save successfully");
}
```

There is no problem with it.

I want to make the heading as the inline something like it.

Comment: do you know why you have received downvote from someone? Due to this: `Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.` So, show what you have now.

Comment: Ignore my above comment. I just saw your edit.

Comment: My recommendation is create an Excel file in the format that you want and then save it as csv. Then open it in notepad. See how the data is aligned. Simply create that in C#

Comment: could you show that part of code which create `report variable`?

Comment: String report = reportDocument.getExcelReport(); & sorry for delay

Comment: getExcelReport(); //it's api

Comment: as far as I know CSV will not manage to keep information about merged cells (first line in desire output). After the file is open you will get `Personal information` in A1, B1 will be empty, C1 will hold `Working info` and D1 will be empty, too. is it ok?

Comment: @GOPI do you want to format heading in csv-file(`.csv`), not in Excel file (`.xlsx`)? If "yes", then I suggest you to clearly  specify it in the question title and the body if you want to get relevant answers (my edit with this clarifications was rejected).

Comment: a CSV file cannot be formatted to be able to show in Excel like you want to do. you'll need to add a "Export to Excel" functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(dialog.FileName); //open the file for writing.
writer.Write("Personal Information" + delimiter + delimiter + "Working INFO" + delimiter);
writer.Write(report); //write the current date to the file. change this with your date or something.
...
```

Csv format doesn't support merged cells, but still you can arrange header line like described above. Just replace delimiter with whatever your cell delimiter is.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using closedxml (https://closedxml.codeplex.com/).

```
 var wb = new XLWorkbook(report); //open spreadsheet
 IXLWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.First(); //get first sheet
 ws.Row(1).InsertRowsAbove(1); //insert row
 ws.Cell("A1").Value = "Personal Information";
 ws.Cell("A4").Value = " Working INFO";
 ws.Range("A1:A3").Row(1).Merge(); // merge first title
 ws.Range("A4:A6").Row(1).Merge(); // merge second
 wb.SaveAs(writer);
```

You can also open csv's and save as csv

Answer (score -3):

1. Firstly create your excel file template in excel and format it as you want.
2. Put only one line where lots of rows will be printed.
3. Put labels into the data row to replace with real data.
4. Save it as MHT file. (styles will be saved, too like html)
5. Open the mht file with text editor.
6. Put < !#> at the begining and end of the data row so that you can split the file content from your program and populate real data lines dynamically by replacing your labels with real properties.

   ```
   <!#>
   <tr height=3D20 style=3D'height:15.0pt'>
   <td height=3D20 class=3Dxl67 style=3D'height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>[id]=</td>
   <td class=3Dxl67 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none'>[name]</td>
   <td class=3Dxl67 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none'>[company<span     style=3D'display:none'>]</span></td>
   <td class=3Dxl67 style=3D'border-top:none;border-left:none'>[destination]=</td>
   </tr>
   <!#>
   ```
7. Save the file from text editor.
8. From your program, you will read the mht file content, you will split it with the < !#> and multiply the data row part, append all together and save to another file..thats it..

Answer (score -5):

You need to have installed Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office.

After that create common .NET project and add the reference to COM object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll via 'Add Reference..' dialog.

```
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);

//Get All available worksheets
//Excel.Sheets excelSheets = wb.Worksheets;

//Get Specific WorkSheet
string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
Excel.Worksheet newSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.get_Item(currentSheet);
newSheet.Cells[i, j].HorizontalAlignment = ExcelAlignment.xlLeft; //or Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft
```

Comment: How this answers question?

Comment: This tells you that there are alot of built-in features in Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office so you can use the Merge property to do your required formatting.